# Pip can't build wheels for pyproject.toml projects because it can't find "--plat-name."

Tags: python, pip, python-moderngl

I'm trying to install moderngl using pip. Of course,

```
python -m pip install moderngl
```

It failed to build wheels for moderngl and one of its dependencies, glcontext. In both cases, it gave me the same error message:

```
error: --plat-name must be one of ('win32', 'win-amd64', 'win-arm32', 'win-arm64')
```

I am certainly, certainly running a 64-bit AMD processor on a Windows machine. How do I make sure pip/pyproject.toml/whatever knows this? With the double-hyphen, I'd assume this is a CLI argument

```
python -m pip install moderngl --plat-name 'win-amd64'
```

but I want to double check and not break things. Is this the safe choice? Or am I way off base? Is there some boilerplate thing I needed to do between installing pip and using it? Either way, what happens if I change the --plat-name argument?

Answer (score 0):

Still don't know *what* the problem was precisely, but now I know vaguely, and the solution.

I had installed Python 3.10.8, pip, pipenv, etc. through mingw64. This seems to lag behind on providing the latest versions of things. It couldn't give me the newest pip or pipenv at the time of this question. And although Python 3.10.8 was exactly the version I wanted, something in there was just messed. Using the recommended installer from python.org and installing pipenv with pip cleared it up (except that pipenv is still trying to use my bad install by default).

Still curious if anyone has insight into what happened. Was --plat-name untraceable for my original python install because of the container it was in?

Comment: Seems like broken or old python install or something wrong with paths.